# Multiple if conditionals to change element attributes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, if-statement, aos.js

I am showing preloader only once per session and also using AOS to animate on scroll (on page load in this case). Because my preloader lasts 2 seconds, I delayed AOS in order to animate elements after the preloader disappears.

Since preloader will show only once, I don't want to delay content showing when there's no preloader, after I return to the same page. I wrote a script to change elements' attributes, but somehow it doesn't work.

I want the code to work only if the preloader-wrapper doesn't exist, or if it exists but has a display: none CSS attribute.

```js
function aosDelay() {

    var elmPreloader =  document.getElementsByClassName('preloader-wrapper')[0];
    
    if (elmPreloader.length < 1 || elmPreloader.css('display') == 'none') {

      $('.layer').setAttribute('data-aos-delay', 0);
      $('.intro').setAttribute('data-aos-delay', 0);
      $('.social-wrapper').setAttribute('data-aos-delay', 0);

    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="layer" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="3000">
<div class="intro" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="3000">
<div class="social-wrapper" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="3000">
```

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: i think your `aosDelay` function only runs one when session starts and doesn't run again when you return to the same page.

Comment: @Ouroborus it does nothing. Maybe I didn't write the statements correctly?

Comment: @Layhout No, it's not the problem. I called the function on page switch. I am using Barba, every other function works except this one.

Comment: WIth just your snippet, you never call `aosDelay()` and, even if you did, you use `[0]` and then try to get `.length` from the results which, of course, causes the script to terminate. Then, `.css()` isn't a javascript thing, it's jQuery which you're not using in that spot.

Comment: yeah, maybe something like `if (!elmPreloader || elmPreloader.css('display') == 'none') { ... }` might help.

Comment: @Ouroborus here's the thing, I tested this with another code such as addClass. It works. But setAttribute("class", "blah") simply doesn't work. I removed the statements, just used one single line of code to test.

Comment: @Layhout it's not a statement problem, I tried it... But setAttribute. :(

Comment: jQuery doesn't have `.setAttribute`, that's a javascript element thing. `.addClass` is a jQuery thing, not a javascript thing. It seems like a lot of your problems are resulting from mixing javascript element manipulation with jQuery element manipulation.

Comment: @Ouroborus You should have pointed out the problem immediately. When I posted the question, I didn't know if the problem lies in the statements or in the code inside of it. All I needed to do was to switch from jQuery to JS selector in order to make setAttribute to work. So, not $('.intro').setAttribute('data-aos-delay', "0"); but document.getElementsByClassName('intro')[0].setAttribute('data-aos-delay', "0");. You just should have posted the answer. Not everyone is a master in programming as you are, so feel free to help when you see the mistake.

Comment: I don't consider myself an expert and it took me a while to realize what the general theme of your errors was. Consider that if I hadn't commented, you would've had a lot less to go on.

Comment: Thank you anyways. I think you should just post the answer that I should have used JS selector with setAttribute, so I can accept it and we can help other people who come across the same problem.